# Computation of the Lusztig a-function

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

See for example https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869387901542 for the definition of the Lusztig a-function.

> Question 1: Is there a table for the values of Lusztig's a-function for a given Dynkin type?

Can one at least find those values when the corresponding simple Lie-algebra has rank <=4? I try to find a reference for the case $G_2$ especially.

> Question 2: Is there a computer program to calculate those values for small Dynkin types?

Comment: If $W$ is a finite Weyl group then it is known that for $w \in W$ we have $\mathbf{a}(w) = \mathbf{a}_{\lambda}$ for some complex irreducible character $\lambda \in \mathrm{Irr}(W)$, see Prop. 2.3.14 of the book by Geck–Jacon. The values $a_{\lambda}$ have all been computed by Lusztig (naturally) and are contained in the CHEVIE software maintained by Jean Michel. See also Chapter 6 of the book by Geck–Pfeiffer. There combinatorial descriptions are given for $\mathbf{a}_{\lambda}$ when $W$ is classical.

Comment: @JayTaylor Thank you. That probably answers my questions, so you might want to turn this into an answer. Can you give an example, for example for G2, with which commands one can obtain those values using GAP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Addition to Geck-Pfeiffer: Small values of the **a**-function are also contained in Geck, Jacon - Representations of Hecke algebras at roots of unity. In particular, for $G_2$ it's in Table 1.3.; for $F_4$ it's table 1.2.; other values are available through combinatorially formulas (for example type $A$ is completely covered in section 2.8) and Remark 1.3.11 contains a fairly straight-forward algorithm to compute the **a**-function in general.